# DataGrid Command Binding Access DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In my application I use the `MVVM` patern. I have set the `DataContext` to my ViewModel and declared a `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="collectionView"                         
                      Source="{Binding FiltredDataGridItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Parent.Name"/>
   </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I use this `CollectionViewSource` as my DataGrid `ItemsSource`

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource collectionView}}">            
</DataGrid>
```

It works fine, but I want to use `ICommand` which is declared in my ViewModel

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn >
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
      <CheckBox x:Name="SelectAll"
                Content="Select All">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckAllCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="UnChecked">
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UnCheckAllCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
       </CheckBox>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And I get these errors

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CheckAllCommand' property not found on 'object' ''CheckBox' (Name='SelectAll')'. BindingExpression:Path=CheckAllCommand; DataItem='CheckBox' (Name='SelectAll'); target element is 'InvokeCommandAction' (HashCode=39571581); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnCheckAllCommand' property not found on 'object' ''CheckBox' (Name='SelectAll')'. BindingExpression:Path=UnCheckAllCommand; DataItem='CheckBox' (Name='SelectAll'); target element is 'InvokeCommandAction' (HashCode=15035499); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Can you guys help me? How I can get access to a command from my view model

**Edit:**

I have declared the DataContext by inheriting from `BasePage`

```
public partial class LoginPage : BasePage<LoginViewModel>
```

BasePage implementation

```
public class BasePage<VM> : Page
    where VM : BaseViewModel, new()                                         
 {                                                                     
    public VM ViewModel
    {
        get => _ViewModel;
        set
        {
            if (_ViewModel == value)
                return;

            _ViewModel = value;

            DataContext = _ViewModel;
        }
    }                                                                  
    public BasePage()
    {
        ViewModel = new VM();
    }                                                                       
 }
```

Comment: Command binding is looking for command in `collectionView` item, not in the entire viewmodel. You have set the datacontext for column or use relative source binding. Can you share your ViewModel with commands? And where it's set as `DataContext`

Comment: My commands now implement only output to console, because I want figure out How to get access. And my DataContext work to other element of my page witch not in DataGrid.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski And I edit question and show implementation.

Comment: Where is the check and uncheck commands are declared, and what is the data context of page with grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to set DataGrid 'Name' property, then pass it to Command. For example

```
<DataGrid Name="dgItems" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ....> 
    .....
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckAllCommand, ElementName =dgItems}"/>
    ....
    ....
</DataGrid>
```